# Counter in JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set up a counter with 3 attempts. An alert box has to show the remaining attempts. When I test it, the script won't run.

Here's my code:

**JQUERY**

```
var counter = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nummer").click(function() {

        var nummer = $(this).text();

        $("#display").append(nummer);

        if ($("#display").text().length > 5) {
            controle();
        }
    });
});

function controle() {

    if ($("#display").text() == 1234) {
        alert("correct");
    } else {
        while (counter > 0) {
            alert(counter - 1 "pogingen");
        }
        alert("you failed");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="display"> </div>
<div id="toetsen">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop1">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop2">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: If you open the console, what error does it show ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this :

```
alert(counter - 1 "pogingen");
```

With this :

```
alert((counter - 1)+"pogingen");
--counter;
```

Also make sure to indent your code properly so you don't get lost.

Comment: `When I test it, the script won't run.` How will you explain this

Answer (score 1):

use the below code, in alert you missed the concat operator

```
function controle() {

    if ($("#display").text() == 1234) {
        alert("correct");
    } else {
        while (counter > 0) {
            alert((counter-1)+"pogingen");
            counter = counter-1; // decrement the value
        }
        alert("you failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your alert contains a syntax error. You should be concatenating the string value using `+`

  ```
  alert(counter - 1 + " pogingen");
  ```
- `counter - 1` however, will always yield `2`. At some point you need to actually set the value. Most readable would be `counter = counter - 1`, but the shortest is to decrement it by one just before the value is accessed in the alert, using `--counter`:

  ```
  alert(--counter + ' pogingen');
  ```
- In deciding whether to test the given value, you're checking `$("#display").text().length > 5`. If the correct answer is indeed `1234`, you will never achieve this if you only test the value once its length is greater than 5.
- You are using a `while`. That will simply loop until the condition is false. In your case, since you're not decrementing the value, it will never be, and you have an infinite loop of alerts. If you introduce the decrement like above, all your guesses will be used up at once. You want to use `if ... else` rather than `while`, to only test for the *current* value of `counter` and then move on.
- Again, if the correct answer is indeed `1234`, you can never achieve this, since there is no `4` button.
- At last, the only thing you ever do is to *append* to the value. After each guess, you will need to clear it to allow a new guess. Set `$('#display').text('');` at a convenient point, such as after showing the alert.

---

```js
var counter = 3, correctAnswer = '1234';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nummer").click(function() {
    var nummer = $(this).text();
    $("#display").append(nummer);

    if ($("#display").text().length >= correctAnswer.length) {
       controle();
    }
  });
});

function controle() {
  if ($("#display").text() == correctAnswer) {
    alert("correct");
  } else {
    if(counter > 0) {
      alert(--counter + " pogingen");
    } else {
      alert("you failed");
    }
    $('#display').text('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="toetsen">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop1">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop2">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop3">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! But when I copy this code and run it, the first time I want to give the code, the alert comes already after 2 numbers. Thereafter, the code works fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Manariba: The decision whether or not to run `controle` is still based on the *text length* of `#display`. I'm guessing you have linebreaks or other whitespace in your code that adds to the length initially, but it works the second time around because it is being set to zero length with `.text('')`. To solve this, remove the whitespace in your markup, perform an initial reset with `$('#display').text()`, or remove the whitespace from the condition with `$.trim($('#display').text()).length >= ...`

Comment: One question: when I enter the code the first attempt correctly, there comes the "wrong" alert. The second attempt it works...

Comment: It doesn't in my example above. I don't know without seeing your updated code, but if it works on successive attempts, chances are you're dealing with whitespace there as well. Try logging the actual values to console to see what you're comparing.